# How to make a mask in Excel with vba?

Tags: excel, vba, mask

I have created a user form in Excel which has lets say 3 fields. `name1`, `brc1` and `tmx1`. The user can type in the field `tmx1` any number from 1 to 9999. I want the time he clicks the <kbd>send</kbd> button to send a masked number as follows `0000` to another ecxel named `data.xls` For example if user types in field `tmx1` **21**  I want the program to send **0021** if he types **321** to send **0321** if it is 4 numbers then it is fine, and so on.

Part of my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Z:\Tameio\data.xls"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row

Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = name1.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = brc1.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = tmx1.Text
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: I believe the search term you were looking for was "padding".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Format` function for masking. Take this function stub for example:

```
Public Function Masking(Data As Integer) As String
    Masking = Format(Data, "0000")
End Function

Sub Test_Masking()
    Debug.Print Masking(1)
    Debug.Print Masking(12)
    Debug.Print Masking(123)
    Debug.Print Masking(1234)
    Debug.Print Masking(12345)
End Sub
```

Results:

```
0001
0012
0123
1234
12345
```

Applying that to your case:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="Z:\Tameio\data.xls"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    lastrow = 10  ' change this to whatever you prefer

    Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = name1.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = brc1.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "'" & Format(tmx1.Text, "0000")
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Based on the excellent suggestion from Mat's Mug, here's a more versatile formatting function:

```
Public Function Masking(Data As Integer, TotalLengthWithZeroPad As Integer) As String
    Masking = Format(Data, String(TotalLengthWithZeroPad, "0"))
End Function

Sub Test_Masking()
    Dim totallength As Integer
    totallength = 10 ' how long will our string's total length be?
    Debug.Print Masking(1, totallength)
    Debug.Print Masking(12, totallength)
    Debug.Print Masking(123, totallength)
    Debug.Print Masking(1234, totallength)
    Debug.Print Masking(12345, totallength)
End Sub
```

Result

```
0000000001
0000000012
0000000123
0000001234
0000012345
```

Comment: That was it? Thank you very much, simple and clear answer!!

Comment: For a more versatile solution you could make the function take an `Integer` parameter for the total length, and generate the `"0000"` string from it instead of hard-coding the padding into the padding function.